# how to encrypt the altbeacon data to aes-ecb format

Tags: aes, altbeacon, android-ibeacon

How to encrypt altbeacon to aes-ecb format.
I have been using flutter but on flutter side. 
I guess it can't be encrypted as the data passed to altbeacon library is in beacon data format.

```
 beaconTransmitter?.startAdvertising(beacon, object : AdvertiseCallback() {
      override fun onStartSuccess(settingsInEffect: AdvertiseSettings?) {
        super.onStartSuccess(settingsInEffect)
        advertiseCallback(true)
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using encryption with bluetooth beacons is very complex for a number of reasons:

- Bluetooth beacons have a small payload of about 22 usable bytes, which is way too small for a full encrypted message.  As a result, beacons typically use a one-way hash that is stripped down to a smaller number of bytes after applying a specific encryption algorithm.
- Standard beacon formats like iBeacon, AltBeacon and Eddystone-UID divide up this limited payload into fields that are meant to be clear-text (unencrypted) identifiers.
- Formats like Eddystone-EID which do use encryption require complex systems to configure each beacon transmitter with a clock-specific hash, and then decode this using a matching algorithm on the receiving side.  They then strip down the encrypted payload to just a few bytes.

If you want to crate a hash with an encryption algorithm and then pare the result down to an 8-byte payload, you can transmit it in an Eddystone-EID frame like below. Just replace the 8 bytes in "0x0001020304050607" with your hashed data.

```
Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
        .setId1("0x0001020304050607") // Encrypted Identifier
company code
        .setTxPower(-59)
        .build();
BeaconParser beaconParser = new BeaconParser()
        .setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_EID_LAYOUT);
BeaconTransmitter beaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(getApplicationContext(), beaconParser);
beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon, new AdvertiseCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Advertisement start failed with code: "+errorCode);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Advertisement start succeeded.");
            }
        });
```

For this to be compliant with the Eddystone-EID spec, there are very specific requirements you need to take in producing your hashed bytes.  If you don't care about meeting the spec, you are welcome to generate those bytes any way you wish so long as they meet your own use case.